# Combination charts - Word chart with bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I am using highcharts for one of my projects and I want to know if it is possible to have a combination chart of bar chart and word cloud chart. Something like shown below

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this or is there any open source chart libraries which do this.

**What I have tried**:

I have looked for all the available chart libraries and did not find any suitable options. Since its the starting point, there is nothing much to be specified.

Please help. I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and add separate containers with `wordcloud` charts:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var points = this.series[0].points;

            points.forEach(function(p) {
                var wContainer = $('<div>');

                wContainer.addClass('wordCloudContainer');

                wContainer.css({
                    top: this.plotTop,
                    left: p.plotX
                });

                $('#mainContainer').append(wContainer);

                Highcharts.chart(wContainer[0], {
                    chart: {
                        width: p.pointWidth + 40,
                        height: 200
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'wordcloud',
                        data: [
                            ['one', 1],
                            ['two', 2],
                            ['three', 3]
                        ]
                    }]
                });
            }, this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2jahsfyp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: But if you see it in full screen, the chart is displayed side by side, !! Any solution for that ?

Comment: Hi @Vikhyath Maiya, I wanted to show you the general concept. You need to change the calculations a bit and CSS styles. Please check the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8vna4peu/

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks :)